# How to data-table show name from series in xAxis

Tags: highcharts

### How to data-table show name from series in xAxis

I'm doing Drilldown chart but I have stuck in trouble Categories in    data-table

I want to fetch data datatable like a picture :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6N6E.png)

example datatable:
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/studies/exporting-table/)

now I use xAxis:

```
   xAxis:
{
type: 'catagories'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the data table generated by the export module? It should accomplish your requirement.

```
  exporting: {
    showTable: true
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3d6u45L8/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.showTable

---

EDIT

According to the comment - I did some changes in the drawTable custom code to draw labels for the xAxis category type:

```
  for (let i in ticks) {
    if (ticks[i].label) {
      renderer.text(
          ticks[i].label.textStr,
          cellLeft + cellPadding,
          tableTop + (i) * rowHeight - cellPadding + 40
        )
        .css({
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        })
        .add();
    }
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lxtekgd9/

Comment: If I use this way, it's can't export data-table pdf or PNG picture

Comment: @TeeraphongSingsaro I see, check my edit